# Double summation squared

Tags: summation

I need to calculate $(\sum_i \sum_tx_{i,t}-1)^2$. I know that
$$
\sum_i \left(\sum_t x_{i,t}-1 \right)^2 = \sum_i\left(2\sum_t\sum_{u>t}x_{it}x_{iu} - \sum_tx_{it} +1\right)
$$ 
from the common square of a sum, and normal binomial formula, but I'm not sure on how to approach adding the second sum into the square. I appreciate any help!

Comment: It is $$\left(\sum_i \sum_t x_{i,t}\right)^2-2\left(\sum_i \sum_t x_{i,t}\right)+1$$ which you can further expand

Comment: But how to solve the first square in here? I only know how to square a single not a double sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the shorthand $u_i = \sum_t x_{i,t}$ to get
$$
\left(\sum_i \sum_t x_{i,t} - 1\right)^2
 = \left(\sum_i u_i - 1\right)^2
$$
and apply the Binomial theorem to $u_i$ and then back-substitute.

Comment: That's neat, I didn't of that. Thanks!